# Want to display a box where I set the color, but a span with no content doesn't render?

Tags: html, css

I have a span tag where I set a class to this:

```
.some-box {
  width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}


<td>
<span class="some-box" style="background-color:#333333;"></span>
</td>
```

It is just an empty box with a color, but it doesn't render anything currently.

How can I fix this?

I tried putting img tag inside with a transparent gif but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bXbYd/1/)

```
.some-box {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display:block;
}
```

only block level elements use width and height.  span is inline by default.

Comment: so a div would be better to start off with than a span? since I don't need to set it to block right?

Comment: @codecompleting correct.  There is virtually no difference between a div and a span beside the fact that the one is a block level element and the other is an inline element.

Comment: @codecompleting see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/znhDx/) to compare div and block level span

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding `display:block` to the css of the span?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the height or width of an inline element. Inline elements are elements that naturally display without "page-breaking" before and after the element. Divs for instance, are block level. To set the width and height of an inline element, you need to set the display property to block, like so.

```
span { display: block }
```